# Evaluating limits: rationalize denominators or divide by denomators highest power first?

Tags: limits

I am unclear on the order of operations and which has precedence.

When evaluating Lim x->4 ( ( 1/sqrt(x) - 4) / (x - 4) ).

Should I divide the numerator and denomator through by x first or should I rationalize the sort first?

What is the standard rule on precedence?

Comment: Please use the body of the Question to give a complete problem statement.  A terse statement leaves the Reader wondering what would actually by helpful to you (by way of an Answer).  Avoid Questions that invite extended discussion, and for other aspects of formulating good Questions, see the [Help Center FAQ](http://math.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean
$\lim_{x\to 4} \dfrac{  \frac1{\sqrt{x}} - 4} {x - 4}$
or
$\lim_{x\to 4} \dfrac{  \frac1{\sqrt{x} - 4}} {x - 4}$
or something else entirely
(such as
$\lim_{x\to 4} \dfrac{  \frac1{\sqrt{x - 4}}} {x - 4}$
)
?

If either of the first two,
since the numerator
does not approach zero as
$x \to 4$
but the denominator does,
the limit is infinity.

Comment: How do you mark up your math like that? It is this one http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+%28%281%2Fsqrt%28x%29+-+4%29+%2F+%28x+-+4%29%29+x+-%3E4&h=1

Comment: I was more concerned with evaluating the limit and the methods of reaching the anwser than the answer itself. I am confused on this one as well in evaluating it by hand, lim x->4 ( (sqrtx) - 4) / (x - 4) . So should I take the conjugate or simply multiply the top and bottom by (1 / x) ? And what is the though process in making that decision? Thank you :)